# app crashes right after splash screen in xcode 4 / ios 5 beta

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

i am having problems with the new xcode 4.2 and beta ios 5. My app compiles and works in Debug mode both on the simulator and a device. When i build an adhoc build, archive it and install it on the device - the app crashes right after the splash screen giving me the following stack (which may be  different at times, but always deriving right from main.m):

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x33b8932c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                  0x33a17f58 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib                  0x33a10fe8 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                    0x34d0df64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                    0x34d0b346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x378452dc _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                    0x34d0b3be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                    0x34d0b44a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                    0x34d0c81e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                    0x3784522e objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                     0x31538546 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                     0x315383a6 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  UIKit                              0x3462ead8 -[UIApplication _run] + 544
13  UIKit                              0x3462bdc0 UIApplicationMain + 1084
14  tflow3                             0x001122fe main (main.m:14)
15  tflow3                             0x0005ed94 0x5d000 + 7572
```

Since the app works when debugged on the device i guess (and hope) my adhoc release configuaration has something going wrong. I'd appreciate any help.